# RxJS .toPromise returns only one value

Tags: rxjs

I'm using RxJS 6.2.1 and I'm trying to convert an observable to a promise

If I create a simple range observable using subscribe, I get values emitted over time.

```
import { range } from 'rxjs'

const source$ = range(0, 10);
source$
  .subscribe(
    x => console.log(x),
    err => console.log(err),
    () => console.log('complete')
  )
```

But how do I convert this whole thing back to a promise?  I tried `.toPromise()` but I only get back a single value, which is "9"

```
import { range } from 'rxjs'

const source$ = range(0, 10);
source$
  .toPromise()
  .then(x => console.log('x', x)) . //only get back "9"
  .catch(err => console.log('err', err))
```

How would I rewrite this so that I get back an array from 0 through 9?

Comment: Have you tried using `.toArray` and then `.toPromise`? Something like that should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will turn all values from your observable stream into an array and resolve the array as a promise value.

```
of('a','b','c','d').pipe(
  toArray()
).toPromise().then(val => console.log(val))
```